# maxima find root of equation

Tags: calculus

Good morning everyone,

Im trying to get used to using maxima.

Specifically the find root function.

To find the root of this equation:

$0.85 = \frac{16}{(19.62 (\sin x + \frac{5}{12}\cos x)}$

So I have entered the following into maxima:

find_root(0.85 = 16/(19.62*(Sin*x + 5/12*cos*x)),x,1,2);

Have I made any obvious mistakes? I haven't slept much so im really hoping someone will spot a syntax error or something as I think ive become blind by looking at it so much!

EDIT:

I have tried this equation in Maxima and its not doing anything at all, which is why I assume it is incorrect. :)

Comment: This question is on topic here. Aside from Mathematica which has its own SE, math-related programming languages are on-topic here (see the discussion on Math Meta SE on [is MATLAB on topic?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11471/is-matlab-on-topic-reprise)).

Comment: However, as the OP you can probably put the equation into Maxima yourself, and check if it agrees with the result from Wolfram Alpha or a graphic tool such as GeoGebra. One way to also [improve your question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) is to also add where your question is from.

Comment: This part `Sin*x + 5/12*cos*x` is wrong, should be `sin(x) + 5/12*cos(x)`. You have also missed a closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

HINT

Transpose and go towards sine of angle sum

$$ \dfrac{ 16 \cdot 12}{(0.85)19.62 (13)}=\frac{12  \sin x + 5 \cos x }{13} $$

with $$ \sin \theta= \dfrac{5}{13} \,$$ etc.